# Recalculate total on same page using form

Tags: html, forms, session, vbscript, asp-classic

I have two pages for an order form and then the order details to process. The order details page calculates selection costs from the form page and calculates a total. I am trying to incorporate a "tip" selection on the processing page that will recalculate the total on the same page.

This is where I would like to select the tip percentage and then recalculate the total:

```
...
<form action="" method="post" name="tip">
    <select name="tip" selected="None">
        <option value="None"<%=tipAddNone%>>None</option>
        <option value="10%"<%=tipAdd10%>>10%</option>
        <option value="15%"<%=tipAdd15%>>15%</option>
        <option value="20%"<%=tipAdd20%>>20%</option>
    </select>
</form>
...
```

I am calculating the total determined by the session variables created.

```
dim total
session("total") = session("subtotal") + session("taxamount")
```

I tried to create conditions if tip is selected here:

```
'Tip
dim tipAdd10, tipAdd15, tipAdd20, tipAddNone, tip
if request("tip") <> "None" then
    session("tip") = request("tip")
end if 

if request("tip") = "10%" Then
    tip = tip * session("subtotal")
elseif session("tip") = "15%" Then
    tip = tip * session("subtotal")
elseif session("tip") = "20%" Then
    tip = tip * session("subtotal")
elseif session("tip") = "None" Then
    tip = 0
end if
```

I would like to be able to select a tip percentage from a drop down list and have the total, which was originally below, recalculate with the applied tip on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

you can use have every amount in hidden element in form and then use javascript to calculate and show them through javascript..

another way to call ajax call and use tip in calculation and then show them on the same page below

or if you want to post  page  and calculate then here is what you want

```
<form action="" method="post" name="tip">
<select name="tip" selected="None">
    <option value="0" <% if tip="0" then response.write "selected" end if %>>None</option>
    <option value="10" <% if tip="10" then response.write "selected" end if %>>10%</option>
    <option value="15"<% if tip="15" then response.write "selected" end if %>>15%</option>
    <option value="20" <% if tip="20" then response.write "selected" end if %>>20%</option>
</select>
```

```
dim tip,tipAmount
tip = request("tip")
session("tip")=tip 
tipAmount= (tip * session("subtotal"))/100
```

use this code and let me know is this you want it